# How to select single elements in swiftui's Canvas preview?

Tags: swiftui

I know that cmnd-click can select elements in the Canvas preview window. But often, when there are many elements inside NavigationView, cmnd-click will select all of this.

```
NavigationView {
                    List {             
                        DateView()

                        Picker(selection: $transactionType, label: Text("Picker")) {
                                Text("All").tag(0)
                                Text("Income").tag(1)
                                Text("Expenses").tag(2)
                        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                            .padding()

                        ForEach(0 ..< 12) {item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: TransactionsDetailsView()) {
                            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                                Text("29/08/2019")
                                Spacer()
                                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                                    Text("+ 1 500 THB")
                                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                    Text("morning")
                                }
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitle("Transactions")
                    }
                }
```

I come from web dev background, so I assumed that I could select each of the elements in Canvas. The same in web inspetor in Safari. Am I wrong? Or is there a way of selecting more details on Canvas?